# Classification method for dataset where the number of features is much smaller than the number of samples

Tags: classification, data-mining

I am searching for a classification method, which is able to work well also when the number of features is much smaller than the number of samples.

In my case, I have to work with a dataset composed by 388 samples and 14 features, which are:

- nominal (5 categories) (1 feature)
- nominal (2 categories) (13 features)

The target variable is nominal (6 categories).

Comment: This question is redundant with this question ... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181588/very-low-out-of-bag-score-after-applying-random-forest#comment344672_181588  Any reason you're asking it twice?

Comment: @DJohnson I think it is not redundant because that question is a specific problem with Random Forest. This one is to search for a different method. Anyway if it is really redundant I will close it.